# How to delete the reference object that will not delete the referred object in Django?

Tags: django

Here I've two models. one is **Contact** and another one is **Sent_replies**. If client wants to contact with admin his information will be stored in **Contact** model. So here I want that if admin replies to that client, that specific information will be deleted from **Contact** model without deleting the record which is in **Sent_replies**. How can I do that.

**models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    message_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class Sent_replies(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(Contact,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    subject = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    reply = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.message.name
```

Comment: Do you know signals in Django ?

Comment: no I'm pretty new in django

Comment: look at my answer and let me know for any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a new field `is_deleted` that can be marked as `True for replied message` and `False for not replied yet message`

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    message_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False) #new

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

2. now every time you created a sent_replie you can marked it as `is_deleted = True`   that method is called `soft deletion`

To filter which message are not yet replied you can do this

```
not_replied = Contact.objects.filter(is_deleted=False)
```

Do not forget to make migrations and migrate and if you have a question please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to archive...

I would suggest making third model called for example ContactRequest.

It will have foreign key to Contact which will store contact informations.

Then after admin reply to ContactRequest you can link reference to Contact instance in Sent_replies and delete ContactRequest instance instead.

Answer (score -1):

Then the message set be set to NULL

```
message = models.ForeignKey(Contact,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```